# Why is the Symmetric Traveling Salesman Polytope not a full dimensional polytope?

Tags: combinatorics, polyhedra

The symmetric travelling salesman polytope (STSP) is defined as the convex hull
of incidence vectors of Hamiltonian cycles.

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$, an incidence vector is a vector $v$ with length $n$ = $|E|$ and entries $0$ or $1$.
$v_i=1$ means that the edge is considered in the tour represented by this incidence vector.

The dimension $dim(P)$ of a polyhedron $P ⊆ R^n$ is one less than the maximum number of
**affinely independent vectors** in P. If $dim(P)$ = $n$, then we call $P$ full dimensional.

> **Definition:** Let $v_0, v_1.. v_k$ be points in $\mathbb{R}^d$.  These points are called affinely independent if there do not exist real numbers $\alpha_0, \alpha_1...\alpha_k$ that are not all zero such that $\sum_{i=0}^k \alpha_i v_i = 0$ and $\sum_{i=0}^k \alpha_i = 0$.

This is the background definitions of the problem, that might be needed.

My Question is how do we know that we do **not** have $n$ vectors in STSP that are affinely independent. I can not easily think how this is supposed to be obvious.

Here is two scientific papers that mention the fact that STSP is not full-dimensional:

- The paper "Worst Case Comparison Of Valid Inequalities For The TSP" by Michel X. Goemans (1995), and [here](http://www-math.mit.edu/~goemans/PAPERS/Goemans-1995-WorstCaseComparisonOfValidInequalitiesForTheTSP.pdf) is the link. (end of 2nd page)
- "The symmetric traveling salesman polytope and its graphical relaxation: Composition of valid inequalities" by Naddef & Rinaldi (1991) and [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01586945) is a preview link. (middle of 2nd page)

Comment: I am not very familiar with this polytope, so this might be bogus.  However, we know that every Hamilton cycle has exactly $|V|$ edges, and so for every point $x$ in the polytope, we must have $\sum_i x_i = |V|$.  Would this explain why the polytope is not full-dimensional?

Comment: I am not sure. I think it has to do with the number of $|V|$ as well. I just added the definition of affinely independent. But you are saying that there does not always exist a combination of incidence vectors (solutions of the STSP) that satisfy the affinely independent definition? Why is that true?

Comment: An equivalent definition to the polytope being full-dimensional is that it should have $n+1$ points $v_0, ... , v_n $ such that the $n $ vectors $v_i - v_0$, $1 \le i \le n $, span $\mathbb {R}^n $.  However, since $v_j \cdot \mathbf{1} = |V|$ for all $j $, these vectors are all orthogonal to the all-one vector $\mathbf {1} $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All hamiltonian paths have the same number of edges, so the potyptope is contained in a hyperplane.

Answer (score 0):

There are many additional affine constraints that a characteristic vector $\chi$ of a Hamiltonian cycles must satisfy. Besides the one mentioned by Mariano (all these vectors contain the same number of edges), here are further ones:

> For every vertex $v\in V(G)$, consider the set $E_v$ of edges incident to $v$. Exactly two of these are containd in a Hamiltonian cycle. Hence, any characteristic vector $\chi$ of a Hamiltonian cycle satisfies
>   $$\sum_{e\in E_v} \chi_e = 2.$$
>   for all $v\in V(G)$.

This is a set of $|V(G)|$ linear constraints, but not all of them are affinely independent.